# Android, find childviews of parent view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem finding childviews of parent view in android, i do the following

- i have a relative layout with 2 textviews and 1 edit text view(for example call this whole view as c1)
- i add the above view c1 to a linear layout using linearlyt.addView(c1)
- i add multiple such child views to parent view

After adding many such child views to linearlyt, i start filling out the edit text of each child view, the question is How can i get the content/text set in Textview of child view whose edit text is being filled out.TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
public void findEditText(View parentview) {
        if (!(parentview instanceof EditText)) {
            System.out.println(((EditText)parentview).getText());
        }
        // If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
        if (parentview instanceof ViewGroup) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) parentview).getChildCount(); i++) {
                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) parentview).getChildAt(i);
                findEditText(innerView);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is good. If you need something more specific to your case given the constant structure of your rows...:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) yourLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
    TextView textView1 = relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
    TextView textView2 = relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
    EditText editText = relativeLayout.getChildAt(2);
    ...
}
```